# Transport Service does not start

Tags: 2011

We are installing Tridion 2011 SP1 and were able to configure Content Manager. But the Content Distributor Transport Service does not start. It gives a service error stating "Service started and stopped..."

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you are using Java 6 and not Java 7. Tridion 2011 will NOT run with Java 7 (it's not a question of support, as you are finding out it really does NOT run).

If you need Java 7 support, then consider using SDL Tridion 2013 instead. Otherwise, uninstall Java 7 and re-run the Tridion installer - it will automatically install a supported version of Java 6.

Comment: Removed all the Java versions, installed Java 6  and same issue persists. Also checked the other comments for license file and jar files. All looks correct. Any way, we can find out what the actual file is.

Comment: What do you mean with "actual file"? Chances are that something is logged in Windows Event logs - check Application Logs, Tridion logs, etc.

Comment: Ok.. Got some additional information. The service still looks for a Java 7 jvm, which is not there. Uninstalled all java versions and then installed Java 6. Still points to Java 7 only. Is this configured in any Tridion confog file by any chance?

Comment: Nope, Tridion reads it from the registry. What do you see if you type "java -version" in a cmd prompt?

Comment: Thanks.. Got that fixed. There was a registry entry still pointing to jre 7 that was causing the issue. Now that is resolved, but publishing a sample page results in status of "Waiting For Deployment". I know this is the last step. Any help??

Comment: Might be better to put in a new question, other people will not read this deeply buried comment. "Waiting for deployment" means it made it to the deployer and is now waiting for the deployer to finish its job (or start its job, all depends on how you're publishing).

Answer (score 1):

Is this a clean install or an upgrade?

I had a similar issue when upgrading an installation to Tridion 2011 a while ago.  It appears that the following two files are no longer needed and should be removed from the lib directory:

- slf4j-api-1.5.5.jar
- slf4j-jdk14-1.5.5.jar

I seem to remember this being in the upgrade manual, but easy to miss!  (So easy that I can no longer find a reference!)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally check the cd_transport_conf.xml file, if that file is invalid the service will fail while starting.